# Redefining sass variables within media queries

Tags: variables, sass

say this common use case:

```
h2{ // logo
  $width: 146px;
  $height: 22px;
  @include size($width, $height); // previously defined mixin for simple size assignment

  a{
    @include size($width, $height);
  }

  @include mq($medium-aux-up){
    $width: 180px;
    $height: 28px;
    @include size($width, $height);

    a{
      @include size($width, $height);
    }
  }

  @include mq($large-up){
    $width: 220px;
    $height: 34px;
    @include size($width, $height);

    a{
      @include size($width, $height);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to change size in media queries by only overriding $width and $height values? Like this (fake):

```
h2{ // logo
  $width: 146px;
  $height: 22px;
  @include size($width, $height);

  a{
    @include size($width, $height);
  }

  @include mq($medium-aux-up){
    $width: 180px;
    $height: 28px;
  }

  @include mq($large-up){
    $width: 220px;
    $height: 34px;
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no way to change size only by overriding variables. What's more the first code block is much more obvious and easier for understanding.

Comment: too verbose and not DRY.

Answer (score 1):

SCSS:

```
$medium-aux-up: "other";
$large-up: "another";

@mixin mq($size) {
  @media (#{$size}) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin size($width, $height) {
  width:  $width;
  height: $height;
}

h2 {
  &, a {
    @include size(146px, 22px);
  }

  @include mq($medium-aux-up){
    &, a {
      @include size(180px, 28px);
    }
  }

  @include mq($large-up) {
    &, a {
      @include size(220px, 34px);
    }
  }
}
```

CSS is optimised:

```
h2, h2 a {
  width: 146px;
  height: 22px;
}
@media (other) {
  h2, h2 a {
    width: 180px;
    height: 28px;
  }
}
@media (another) {
  h2, h2 a {
    width: 220px;
    height: 34px;
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/ff7c8ebd32b9c79e2d128b798bf64dd1)

Answer (score 0):

For example you can use a function to calculate a length more times depending on media queries. You can also adjust this math like adding n value or whatever you want.

```
$width:100px;
$height:100px;


@function lengthMedia($media){
  $base: 1;
  @if($media == 'xs'){
    $base: 2;
  }
  @else if($media == 'md'){
    $base: 3;
  }

  @return $base * $width;
}

.foo{
  width: lengthMedia('xs');

}

@media (min-width:500){
  .foo{
    width: lengthMedia('md');
  }
}
```